# Performance issue : How to execute Two lambda expression at once?. "Contains" and "Any" operator used

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Sample code

```
var Ids = _db.Projects.Where(Project=>Project.Title!="test23rdoct")
    .Select (pro => pro.Id);

Expression<Func<Company, bool>> masterExpression = 
    Company => Company.Participants.Any(part => ids.Contains(part.Project.Id));

IQueryable<Object> queryEntity = _db.Companies.Where(masterExpression)
```

The above query executing twice. Storing ids in the server(sometime ids are more than 50k count). It causes performance issues. Could anybody suggest how to combine these two queries and execute at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solution for avoiding execution of Lambda twice.  To achieve this I used these extension methods Invoke()  and AsExpandable(). Its available in Linqkit dll.

```
Expression<Func<Company, bool>> masterExpression = Company => Company.Participants.Any(part => masterLamba.Invoke(part.Project));
queryEntity = _db.Companies.AsExpandable().Where(masterExpression);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var queryEntity = _db.Companies.Where(c => c.Partipants.Any(p => p.Project.Title != "test23rdoct"));
```

**EDIT**:
With the complex query, you could also split that:

```
Func<Project, bool> projectFilter = Project => ((Compare(Convert(Project.Title), "a") > 0) AndAlso ((Convert(Project.Title) != "test23rdoct") AndAlso
(Project.Participants.Any(Participant => (Compare(Convert(Participant.ParticipantRole.Name), "Finance") > 0)) AndAlso 
(Project.Participants.Any(Participant => (Convert(Participant.Person.FirstName) != "test1")) AndAlso 
Project.Participants.Any(Participant => (Compare(Convert(Participant.Company.Name), "test") > 0))))));
```

And then do:

```
var queryEntity = _db.Companies.Where(c => c.Partipants.Any(p => projectFilter(p.Project));
```

Comment: It did not work . I dont want to change this expression Project=>Project.Title!="test23rdoct". Its dynamic.

Comment: What do you mean by it not working? When you say dynamic, do you mean the value "test23rdoct" is variable?

Comment: getting Ids query will be dynamic, like below. Project => ((Compare(Convert(Project.Title), "a") > 0) AndAlso ((Convert(Project.Title) != "test23rdoct") AndAlso (Project.Participants.Any(Participant => (Compare(Convert(Participant.ParticipantRole.Name), "Finance") > 0)) AndAlso (Project.Participants.Any(Participant => (Convert(Participant.Person.FirstName) != "test1")) AndAlso Project.Participants.Any(Participant => (Compare(Convert(Participant.Company.Name), "test") > 0))))))

Comment: Pablo, Thanks. It looks like its close to the solution what I am looking for. I got this exception while executing that lambda "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: That is true, EF won't know how to translate an arbitrary expression. Why is it that you have them separate, are you building those conditions using some tool?

Comment: Pablo, I am dynamically generating Lambda expression. That is the master expression, I will be using that across all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this using `Join` suit your needs?

```
Expression<Func<Company, bool>> masterExpression = 
    Company => Company.Participants.Join (Ids, p => p.Project.ID, id => id, (p, id) => p).Any();
IQueryable<Object> queryEntity = _db.Companies.Where(masterExpression);
```

Comment: here you dint mention the expression for getting Ids. This is simple query to get ids,Project=>Project.Title!="test23rdoct". It can be big one, like answered in the previous post.

Comment: You are already filtering by that ID clause in the `Ids` query, which is the first argument of the `Join` (I edited to capitalize it). It will be lazy evaluated during the Join.

Comment: You make it dynamic, you can pass the Ids query in as a `Func<Project, bin>` parameter if desired. I took the thrust of the question as being how to combine the two queries. These construction will run as a single SQL query. It's the `Contains` clause that requires two db calls.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I dont want the Ids to execute as sepearate query. I just want the Ids also should be executed while joining this queries. Basically I dont want to store anyting in the memory. Could share your thoughts how can I get Ids dynamically?